# How to achieve instant hide() of label when text is typed

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text input with a label I've positioned over the top to work as a placeholder. I am familiar with the placeholder attribute, but it is not relevant to this task.

When the user types into the input, the placeholder label hides. But the problem, is that it actually takes a microsecond to happen - its not instant. Meaning you get a delay where the placeholder is covering your first few characters of text.

My html code is:

```
<div class="input-wrap">';

    <div class="label" contenteditable="false">Write something</div>
    <div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.input-wrap').on('keyup','#status-input',function(){

    $('#label').hide();

});
```

**[I've made a codepen example here.](http://codepen.io/robertnorth/pen/ubqdB)**

How to make the label disappear as soon as something is typed without delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `keydown` event instead?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Apxmy

Comment: All this time I thought there was something wrong with the world, but all along it was me.